# homography matrix in akaz algorithm opencv 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

The akaze implementation in opencv 3.1 use a homography matrix

*this is the example of the implementation with the homography matrix :

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_matching/akaze_matching.html

I want to know if

I can use this homography matrix with any image or this homography matrix is only for the specific image in this example and I must generate my homography matrix for every new image  .

thanks :)

Comment: Are you asking if you can use the homography matrix on a different sized image? If the dimensions are the same then it will transform/warp the images in the same way

Comment: No, you cannot use this homography matrix for other images. The homography matrix relates the perspective transformation between two planar surfaces. This geometric constraint allows to discard bad matches. If you want to use this homography matrix in another images, the two plans have to be the same otherwise the homography transformation is not the same.

Comment: EdChum , Catree , how can I generate a Homography matrix for my new image ??

Comment: You can estimate the homography: [cv::findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780). You will have to use a robust method like RANSAC to try to minimize the impact of bad matches. I strongly recommend you to read a course on this topic before anything else, for example: [Lecture 16: Planar Homographies (CSE486, Penn State)](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture16.pdf).